# How does this converge uniformly?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

My teaching assistant told me that $\sum \frac{(-1)^n x^n}{n}$ converges uniformly on $[0,1]$, but I doubt that.

I can only see that it is uniformly convergent on $(-a,a)$ where $0<a<1$.

How do I show that the series is uniformly convergent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the definition of uniform convergence. If $x\ne 0$ and we truncate just after the term $\frac{(-1)^n x^n}{n}$, then the absolute value of the error is $\lt \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$. Since $\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\le \frac{1}{n+1}$ in our interval, for any $\epsilon\gt 0$, there is an $N$ independent of $x$ such that if $n\gt N$ then the absolute value of the truncation error is $\lt \epsilon$.

Comment: I don't get what you mean..

Comment: For $x\ne 0$, this is an alternating series, with terms going down in absolute value, and having limit $0$. A standard result about such series is that the error when you truncate at the term $a_n$ has absolute value less than the first "neglected" term. In our case, the error has absolute value less than $\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$, which is $\le \frac{1}{n+1}$. So if we choose $n+1\gt \frac{1}{\epsilon}$, the error has absolute value $\lt \epsilon$. This is independent of $x$.